# Creating new variables with conditional statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create new variables in Java based on comparison operators (three different variables: one for less than, one for greater than, and one for equal to) to examine the difference between two variables between two years

The data is organized in two categories for two years that add up to 100 for each year, as shown below:

```
2018 X=70%        2019 X=20%
2018 Y=30%        2019 Y=80%
```

I want to make the following statements for both x and y:

- If x 2019 is greater x 2018, then new_variable_decrease
- If x 2019 is less than x 2018, then new_variable_decrease
- If x 2019 is equal to x 2018, then new_variable_no_change

I am new to Java, but this is what I tried and setting a new variable with int and an if statement (which didn't run in the program I'm using-Q)

```
int new_variable_increase;
if (x2019 > x2018) {new_variable_increase}

int new_variable_increase;
if (x2019 > x2018) {new_variable_increase}
```

Comment: Those lines are identical. Also, you haven't asked a question.

Comment: What did you expect to happen as a result of writing an existing variable name as a statement?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to be able to say, for example, that category X decreased 50%, while category Y increased 50%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *existence* (and names) of variables are static, the *values* are dynamic. If the variable doesn't exist, you can't check if it exists, i.e. your code wouldn't compile.

Sounds more like you need an `enum` with values `DECREASE`, `INCREASE`, and `NO_CHANGE`, and a variable of that type, e.g.

```
public enum Difference { DECREASE, INCREASE, NO_CHANGE }
```

```
Difference diff;
if (x2019 < x2018) {
    diff = Difference.DECREASE;
} else if (x2019 > x2018) {
    diff = Difference.INCREASE;
} else {
    diff = Difference.NO_CHANGE;
}
// use variable here
```

Of course, if you *really* want a local variable to only exist under certain conditions, declare the variable inside the `if` or `else` block:

```
if (x2019 < x2018) {
    int new_variable_decrease = 0;
    // use variable here
} else if (x2019 > x2018) {
    int new_variable_increase = 0;
    // use variable here
} else {
    int new_variable_no_change = 0;
    // use variable here
}
```

Another alternative is to have all 3 variables exist, but only one of them have a value, i.e. only one is not `null`:

```
Integer new_variable_decrease = null;
Integer new_variable_increase = null;
Integer new_variable_no_change = null;
if (x2019 < x2018) {
    new_variable_decrease = 0; // 0 auto-boxed to Integer.ZERO
} else if (x2019 > x2018) {
    new_variable_increase = 0; // 0 auto-boxed to Integer.ZERO
} else {
    new_variable_no_change = 0; // 0 auto-boxed to Integer.ZERO
}
// use all 3 variables here.
```